# How to statically type a fallback behaviour in flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am struggling how to properly type in flow a default behaviour of one component without code duplication.
The desired behaviour is like this:

- If the proper values are provided then all must be of the same type and will be used
- If the any of the required values is not provided, fallback to override them all and use certain defaults

So, it is important tho enforce that all the types must align if provided but they must be all optional.

An example could be a tabs react component that takes a list of tab definitions. If you provide a list of tabs with a value property, then use that value to determine the active tab and the initial tab prop must be of that same type. If your tabs do not contain the value, then fallback to index handling and the initial value must be of type number.

Here is what I tried:

```
type Full<T> = {
  children: (T) => Node,
  initialTab: T,
  tabs: { label: string, value: T }[],
}

type Default = {
  children: (number) => Node,
  initialTab: number,
  tabs: { label: string }[],
}

type Props<T> = Full<T> | Default

function Tabs<T>({ className, children, tabs, initialTab }: Props<T>) {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(initialTab)
  return children(activeTab)
  )
}
```

I tried all the variations that I can think of but I still get errors. In the example above for example the default number type does not align with the variable T type so I can not call children with it.

Comment: You could just provide the default type for generic type parameter https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AN6gCuAzgKYDKuAhruQDSi4CeG5oAcrACYcC+oSNlhpQAcmzkaAY1ziA3MlbtQAMWLRoAHgAqoALygAdsTQAjctgB8hwolCgZACxTQeU4wC5QACl0AlIa23HwMDqAoxii4KDTQujTmPrrhjrTmpD5E0Enk0D6kuNhRAOZMAG7xxOQpoPwA2gC64fzKbBwACiIYpHq2Rhpa-ciQxMZyKLDGoImZ-b5ELm4e5MZMGaRMUTFxCUn1Pt2wvf1BBBEy00WgDbKxFeRzTBS4AIKTj3NNdmRUtPRfDtYvE5gEIlJcMRsDNlu5PL57igvklwfwgA

Comment: I see that I simplified my problem too much. Yes, that will default the T to number, but if I want to use some default logic that,  inside the function, flow knows it is a number, it will tell me that number is not compatible with T. I think I will update my question to clarify that.